The right way to create safe transactions in MongoDB
I’m working on a Node.js application using Mongoose and MongoDB. In the following code, I’m using a transaction to handle creating a new topic with an automatically incremented position. My goal is to prevent race conditions where multiple requests might try to increment the position simultaneously and cause conflicts. Does this code guarantee such protection?
Here’s the code:
const createTopic = async (topic: any) => {
  const session = await mongoose.startSession();
  session.startTransaction();

  try {
    // Atomically increment the position and retrieve the last document
    const lastDocument = await Topics.findOneAndUpdate(
      {},
      { $inc: { position: 1 } }, // Increment the highest position by 1
      { sort: { position: -1 }, new: true, session }
    );

    const newPosition = lastDocument ? lastDocument.position : 1;

    const newDocument = new Topics({
      name: topic.name,
      description: topic.description,
      position: newPosition,
    });

    await newDocument.save({ session });
    await session.commitTransaction();
    await session.endSession();

    return { ok: true };
  } catch (error) {
    await session.abortTransaction();
    await session.endSession();

    return { ok: false, error };
  }
};


It's a little unclear but I think you are trying to insert a new topic if there is none with topic.name, and otherwise just increment position.
In that case your {} parameter to findOneAndUpdate matches all topics that exist, not just a specific one you're looking for. We'll need to fix that bug.
As for the race condition, since $inc is atomic by default, you don't need transactions for this, except in the case of a new insertion. We can address that with an index and a check for a unique key error.
Here is a solution without transactions. This requires only one MongoDB call, except in the rare case of two simultaneous insertions. Nnote this can only happen when a name has never been used before and two people suddenly want it at once. In that rare case, we catch the exception and just do the increment.
// In your mongoose model, make sure "name" has a unique index
const Topic = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, unique: true },
  description: { type: String },
  position: { type: Number }
});

// Here is the code for the increment/upsert
try {
  await Topics.updateOne(
    {
      name: topic.name
    },
    {
      $inc: {
        position: 1 
      },
      // In the case of an upsert we must establish name and
      // description values. In the case of an update
      // setting it again is harmless
      $set: {
        name: topic.name,
        description: topic.description
      }
    },
    {
      // insert if it does not exist
      upsert: true
    }
  );
} catch (e) {
  if (e.toString().includes('duplicate')) {
    // Two inserts happened at once. Make sure the second increment
    // occurs
    await Topics.updateOne({
      name: topic.name
    }, {
      $inc: {
        position: 1
      }
    });
  }
}

This will insert a new topic if necessary and update one if not.
However I'll note that if name can be edited, then that is a potential source of race conditions while it is being changed. If name can be edited I would recommend using _id as a key for updates instead.
